# How to migrate from one MC map to another retaining all collected items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to move from one Minecraft map to another while keeping your items from inventory and chests?

Asking more precisely - could this be done with commands? Like export items and their amounts to a file and then import everything according that file using a command?

Comment: You could go to a new map, open the map up to lan, enable cheats and go to game mode 1 and just give yourself the stuff. However alternatively I remember being able to migrate only your character to a new map by changing the sever map (only if you hosted the server, and lot on lan), of course this was also back in I believe 1.1 so it might be changed, and it would only be the stuff your character has on them.

Comment: Not sure if that does the trick, but.. `oldMap/playerdata/` -> `newMap/playerdata/` might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with commands, however you could move the playerdata between the two maps, which will also move your inventory.

Note: This may also move your position in the world.